# IsWeekEnd Expresion in SSIS that is locale-neutral

Tags: ssis

How can I write an SSIS expression that determines whether a date is a weekend day?

I have this expression, but it seems it only 'works on my machine'

```
DATEPART( "Weekday", @[User::CurrentDate] ) ==6 || DATEPART( "Weekday", @[User::CurrentDate] ) ==7
```

After I deploy SSIS package to server, is suddenly changes order of numbers and
Monday became 2.

When on my computer Monday is 1, exactly as I expected.

I checked SQL Server itself, but it seems is something inside SSIS decide if Sunday or Monday is first day.

I cannot find exact question related to this issue.

[image: SSIS Expression]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `DATEFIRST` property in your package, before using this expression?   What exactly did you do when you ""checked SQL Server itself"?

Comment: I run DECLARE @my_date_var DateTime  = GETUTCDATE()
SELECT (((DATEPART(DW, @my_date_var) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) to check what SQL Server have for Monday

Comment: I know nothing about DATEFIRST property of SSIS packages. Where is that?

Comment: Hmm, turns out SSIS servers don't have a DATEFIRST property.   SSIS uses the regional setting for the server, so you would have to change it there.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/46e91abe-f4f6-48f6-a325-5c384c8e0567/first-day-of-the-week-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Impossible. need another solution. Server setting and Workstation setting always different

Comment: where is the server located? Sounds like you have confirmed that the day hasn't changed (still monday) and that Monday just has a different numerical order. but possibly you haven't confirmed that you are getting a 2 and that 2 really is monday? if the server is in a different timezone, could be that it really is Tue? Just in case.

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure your workstation to match the config of the server you want to deploy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you must do this in an SSIS expression, here is one way to work around the problem:   you would compare the DW of your variable to the DW of a known constant (like August 3, 2019, which is a Saturday in any locale that I know of).

In pseudocode,  `IF ( DW(DateVariable) = DW("20190803") OR DW(DateVariable) = (DW("20190803")+1)%7 ) THEN {DateVariable is a weekend}`

Personally, I would look for a way to do this in TSQL.   Import the raw data "as is" into a staging table, and then do the transformation while moving the data to the destination table with a stored procedure.

Comment: That works for me, even if this is kind of workaround

Answer (score 0):

DATEPART("DW",GETDATE()) or DATEPART("WEEKDAY",GETDATE()) works perfectly fine on both SQL server and local.
How are you passing value to @[User::CurrentDate] variable(Please check if same date is set when packages is executed on SQL server and on local)
I changed DateTime on my local and tested your expression as part Of Execute SQL task and Derived Column Transformation which gives me 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday and so on and the result matches with SQL.

SQL query to get day of week:
SELECT GETDATE() Today,DATENAME("DW", GETDATE()) DayofWeekToday,
DATEPART("DW",GETDATE()) DayNumberToday,GETDATE()-1 Yesterday,
DATENAME("DW", GETDATE()-1) DayofWeekYesterday,DATEPART("DW",GETDATE()-1) DayNumberYesterday

Adding more to my answer : There is a difference between DateFirst and DatePart. DateFirst sets first day of the week while Datepart gives you day of the week. use this sql function to check what's your  first day of the week 
Set Datefirst 7 -- To set first day of week (7 = Sunday)
SELECT @@DATEFIRST -- To check first day of week
**Update your system settings to match first day of the week with sql server and you should get same values when you evaluate expression.

Your expression looks good its only your first day of week on local and sql server are not matching.

Once I updated first day of week on SQL, I was able to replicate the issue you are facing.

Comment: When I run SSIS package inside Visual Studio it gives me Monday = 1 , as it runs on my workstation. As I don’t know exactly how SSIS decide What is DATEFIRST when it run on my computer, I assume it probably settings of my computer

Comment: I think when I run SSIS  Package Expression in VISUAL STUDIO 2017. There are no  SQL Server i can reconfigure. I can adapt SSIS to run on server correctly, but when I Debug SSIS inside Visual Studio it gives me different results, so package is not prone to errors.
"Works on my machine" issue